# Better way of searching through lists than using foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

```
list vclAsset<FullAsset>
list callsigns<string>

foreach(FullAsset fa in vclAsset)
{
    if (callsigns.contains(fa.asset.callsign))
    {
         //do something
    }

}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do the above? A FullAsset object contains an Asset object which in turn has a string "Callsign." Each callsign will be unique, so my list callsigns will only have one of each string, and no two FullAsset objects will share an Asset.callsign variable.

In a nutshell I want to pull all the FullAssets that have a certain callsign, but using a foreach seems clumsy (given that the number of FullAssets that could be contained in said list potentially has no upper limit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lambda expression, something like this:

```
foreach(FullAsset fa in vclAsset.Where(a => callsigns.contains(a.asset.callsign))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: +1. you was faster... I have deleted my answers. (it was == your).

Comment: Nicer, but mostly syntactic sugar

Answer (score 3):

If your keys are unique, you can use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) or a [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) to speed up searching.

If you only want to **find** a certain item, you can use the [`List<T>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) method and supply a predicate.

```
FullAsset result = vclAsset.Find
     (fa => callsigns.contains(fa.asset.callsign));
```

or

```
List<FullAsset> results = vclAsset.FindAll
     (fa => callsigns.contains(fa.asset.callsign));
```

If you are using .Net 3.5, LINQ [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) may be a better solution, as others have stated, since it returns an enumerator (lazy evaluation) vs a full List.

Comment: You can also use the List<T>.FindAll and supply the predicate

Comment: Actually I think underneath .FindAll might use a ForEach anyway but it looks neater :-)

Comment: Of course, entire Linq does that, but the point is to avoid repeating foreach statements all the time, and focus on the condition (predicate, comparison, etc).

Comment: LINQ to Objects works with IEnumerable. Zero ExpressionTrees involved. No lazy evaluation for you. And in case i'm wrong - welcome to fix! :)

Comment: I wasn't referring to expression trees, but to the fact that `FindAll` works on a fully instantiated list, and returns a full list of elements, while `Where` checks one element at a time, *yield returing* a single result on each iteration. For example, if you have a `break` statement inside your `foreach` loop, it may never access all the elements in your original enumeration. Or if you are using the `Select` statement to project `Where` results, then the difference will be even bigger, since you will only be projecting one item at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, using linq.

```
var assets=    vclAsset.Where(fullA=>allsigns.contains(fullA.asset.callsign));
```

assets will be some enumerable structure.

I can recommend [100 Linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) for inspiration and learning

Comment: +1 - similar to the answer I used syntactically (if only we could accept two!) - is there a difference in performance, or is it purely an aesthetic change?. Many thanks for the linq examples!

Comment: I had already type half of the response when the other answer arrived. I just wanted to add the link which really helped me out when first exploring Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it counts as more elegant but you can use linq...

```
        var results = from fa in vclAsset
                      where callsigns.Contains(fa.asset.callsign)
                      select fa;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = vclAsset.Where(x=>callsigns.Any(y=>x.asset.callsign==y));
```

P.s. I would rename `vclAsset` and `asset`/`callsign` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Join function to do this.

```
var sortedList = vclAsset.Join(callsigns,
    x => x.asset.callsign, x => x,
    x, y => x);
```

This is the list of vclAssets that have the listed callsign.